# Mysql - Round float to nearest integer

Tags: mysql

How can I round a `FLOAT` to the nearest `INTEGER` in MySql?

I know about the `ROUND()` function already. The reason for my question is that the return value of MySql's `ROUND()` function "has the same type as the first argument" (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

So if I pass in a FLOAT `3.6` then I will get a FLOAT `3.0` as my answer.  How can I instead get an integer `3`?

I have thought about using `FLOOR(ROUND(x))`.  My worry here is that a floating-point rounding issue might result in the wrong answer.  For example, is it possible that something like `ROUND(3.2)` might, due to floating point number implementation return a FLOAT `2.99999999999999999999` and then `FLOOR(ROUND(3.2))` would give the wrong answer `2`.  I also wonder whether there is a more efficient method than combining 2 functions.

Comment: *if I pass in a FLOAT 3.6 then I will get a FLOAT 3.0 as my answer. How can I instead get an integer 3?* Why do you need so? The datatype system in MySQL is soft, so strong datatype makes no sense. *and then FLOOR(ROUND(3.2)) would give the wrong answer 2* Double rounding? Why do you need so? *it possible that something like ROUND(3.2) might, due to floating point number implementation return a FLOAT 2.99999999999999999999* Use not FLOAT but DECIMAL.

Comment: I think your solution if fine. If you're unsure if something is going to work. It's generally a good idea to write some tests for it. Your boss probably won't be ok with you blaming SO for a bug ;-)

Comment: @Akina In this particular case I already have a FLOAT in one table and I need to do a calculation with it and store it in an INTEGER field in another table.  I've got into trouble with floating-point number conversions before so I want to be careful about it.

Comment: @Erik What possible test could I write?  Any number I think of and try to test might work as expected.  But that doesn't mean that it will work for _all_ numbers.

Comment: @DanielHoward that's true. But will you get any better guarantees of a random person of the internet? You can pick a few numbers known to have float rounding errors and test with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options to cast or convert a FLOAT directly to an integer: CONVERT and CAST. Both options work essentially the same way, and both options require making a choice between signed and unsigned integers, so if you are using a mixture of negative and positive numbers between -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, you will have to use signed integers. On the other hand, if you need numbers really big positive numbers up to 4,294,967,295 then you will need to use unsigned integers.

Here are some examples:

```
SELECT CONVERT(-3.2, SIGNED);
```

Produces an output of `-3`

```
SELECT CAST(3.6 as SIGNED);
```

Produces an output of `4`

```
SELECT CONVERT(3.3, UNSIGNED);
```

Produces an output of `3`. **Note:**
If performing arithmetic functions with the converted integers, there are some rules that must be adhered to. Here is a link to additional information on the cast and convert functions: [mySequel_Dev_CastFunctions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: @Daniel Howard It looks like you posted your answer just before I finished typing. We came to the same conclusion

Comment: Thanks Justin - I think you posted your answer about the same time that I reached the same conclusion.  The only thing still bothering me is that I can't find anything in that documention on casting that confirms the rounding behaviour.

Comment: Nesting ROUND inside the cast works to, but before I posted, I created a test column of a float datatype with every decimal extension because I wanted to be sure I was correct before posting, and it formated as expected. It rounded up between .5 and .9 and down between .0 and .4

Comment: I also plugged a negative number into an unsigned cast just to see what would happen. It returned a result, but it was a ridiculous number

Comment: Hmm - I tried `CAST -1.5 AS UNSIGNED` and got 0.  That doesn't seem to be a ridiculous number to me - it's what I would have expected - of all the possible unsigned integers, 0 is the ones closest to -1.5.  But if you got a different value then possibly there are inconsistencies between different MySQL/MariaDB versions and this question might be more awkward than I expected!

Comment: Probably not. I used SELECT CONVERT(-1.1, UNSIGNED), and I got 18446744073709551615 as a result, so it's probably just a difference between the way CAST and CONVERT handles the operation

Comment: I take that back, I got the same result when I used CAST. I'm using MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in my version of MySql at least, the solution is trivial:

`CAST(x AS UNSIGNED)`  (or `CAST(x AS SIGNED)`) seem to have the exact behaviour that I want which is to round to the nearest integer.

Although so far, I can't find anything in the documentation that confirms exactly what the behaviour is when converting FLOAT to INTEGER.  I don't know whether there are implementations out there that might truncate towards zero or use floor instead...

Tests

```
SELECT CAST(-1.8 AS SIGNED); /* -2 */
SELECT CAST(-1.5 AS SIGNED); /* -2 */
SELECT CAST(-1.2 AS SIGNED); /* -1 */
SELECT CAST(1.2 AS SIGNED); /* 1 */
SELECT CAST(1.5 AS SIGNED); /* 2 */
SELECT CAST(1.8 AS SIGNED); /* 2 */

SELECT CAST(-1.8 AS UNSIGNED); /* 0 */
SELECT CAST(-1.5 AS UNSIGNED); /* 0 */
SELECT CAST(-1.2 AS UNSIGNED); /* 0 */
SELECT CAST(1.2 AS UNSIGNED); /* 1 */
SELECT CAST(1.5 AS UNSIGNED); /* 2 */
SELECT CAST(1.8 AS UNSIGNED); /* 2 */
```